# Clipping non-projection elements (orthographic)

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to add "flying" (3D) arcs to my orthographic projection, as shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/5735048), but with clipping instead of the fade effect. This seems difficult since the arcs are created independently of the projection. (Each arc is defined by three points obtained from the projection--the start, end, and great circle midpoint extended along a line from the center of the canvas--but the arc itself is drawn using "2D" cardinal interpolation on the corresponding  points on the svg canvas.)

My first thought was that I might need to do some spherical geometry to get the coordinates where the clipping happens, but now I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this (I'm new to D3).

This is what my map looks like without clipping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also very green to d3, but fortunately I'm also fresh from my own search for a decent solution for clipping flight lines in orthographic. The demo you link to is clever in more ways than one:

1. The arc is drawn from three points interpolated with a [Catmull-Rom curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) in the *projected 2D coordinates* that happens to visually approximate a true circular curve in 3D nicely
2. The line fades with proximity of either of its points to the clipping plane, as you've pointed out

Drawing the spline in the projected, 2D coordinates eliminates any option to split the line before projection and get visual smoothness for cheap, even if d3 had the functionality natively (which I haven't been able to find anyways). That means that interpolation will have to be a lot more manual.

> My first thought was that I might need to do some spherical geometry to get the coordinates where the clipping happens, but now I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this

I eventually settled with what I consider the most obvious option, which unfortunately you're aiming precisely to avoid:

1. Obtain the coordinates of the clipping point by the cross product of the current globe center with the normal to the great circle plane of the arc. Given your origin and destination `Po` and `Pd` respectively and the globe center `C`, you're looking for `C x (Po x Pd)` normalized
2. Interpolate coordinates between your origin and destination using something like d3.geoInterpolate
3. Project interpolated point at the right `scale` (read: elevation) above the ground for that fraction of the flight line
4. Draw one [smoothed] line from the origin to the clipping point along the interpolated points in between, and another from the clipping point to the destination, moving one accordingly to the background. Watch the cases where the whole line is in front or behind the clipping plane.

To figure out where in the flight path you need to splice your clipped point, you will probably need to compare the great angles of your clipping point to one end vs. end-to-end. Note also that performance takes a hit, but you may still be satisfied with the number of flight lines you've drawn in your example.